# How to stop python script when run it from Website (php)

Tags: php, python, linux, raspberry-pi

My Project is Lighting Control on Rasp Pi
by use Rasp Pi as Web Server & Control the light by python script
I use the UI on PHP Website to control the light

Here is my php code

```
<?php
    public function auto1()
    {   
        system('sudo -u root -S python /var/www/4led/chktime1.py');
    }

    public function disauto1()
    {   
        system('echo raspberry | sudo -u root -S pkill -f chktime1.py');
    }
?>
```

when I press the on button on website to turn auto script It call auto1 and work correctly but this is loop script (I intend to make it loop alltime) but when I press the off button It can't close it because the loop of chktime1.py is still working and cannot open other script or command in disauto1. How can I stop this script from PHP command.

Thank you for your helping

Comment: Even when a request is aborted, you have no guarantee that the python script will be halted. You have no control externally.

Comment: Why was this question tagged with [tag:codeIgniter]?  Edited.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Sorry for my poor code I can't make the smarter code than this script .This script will automatically check time from Database every 10 min . If the current time is concurrent with database time the light will open.I try from putty It can interrupt by "ctrl + c" or use command "echo raspberry | sudo -u root -S pkill -f chktime1.py" from other terminal It work very well. But I want to know how to exit the script in same terminal with still looping could you know the other way to stop this script.

Comment: @Sparky because I use Codeigniter Framework on this website

Comment: Your code is not poor, but it is irrevant to the answer. Even the smartest php code cannot guarantee what you want

Comment: If the question is not specifically about CodeIgniter, then please do not tag-spam.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your problem is solved but maybe it helps someone else.
You can Touch a File in PHP and check in your chktime1.py if the file is there or not.

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <input type="submit" name="start" value="start" />
     <input type="submit" name="stop" value="stop" />
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['start'])){
        system('sudo -u root -S python /var/www/4led/chktime1.py');
    }
    if(isset($_POST['stop'])){
        system('sudo -u root -S touch /var/www/4led/stop-script');
    }
?>
```

you can add this to your Python

```
import os, sys

while(true): 
   #your code
   if(os.path.isfile('/var/www/4led/stop-script')):
      break

os.system("sudo -u root -S rm /var/www/4led/stop-script")
```